Can't prevent Typeorm from synchronizing database
I'm using Typeorm with Node.js and MySQL.
I set synchronize:false everywhere but it still synchronizes. How can I make sure not synchronization is performed? It doesn't rebuild some tables properly and I lose some data.
I put the following code in a data-source.ts file inside src folder.
  type: "mysql",
  host: process.env.MYSQL_HOSTNAME,
  port: 3306,
  username: process.env.MYSQL_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
  socketPath: process.env.MYSQL_SOCKET_PATH,
  database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
  synchronize: false,
  logger: new Logger(),
  connectTimeout: 20000,
  dropSchema: false,
  entities: [
    Users,
    Notifications,
    etc...
  ],
  migrations: [],
  subscribers: [], 
});

I also created a ormconfig.ts file in the root directory.
export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
  type: "mysql",
  host: process.env.MYSQL_HOSTNAME,
  port: 3306,
  username: process.env.MYSQL_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
  socketPath: process.env.MYSQL_SOCKET_PATH,
  database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
  synchronize: false,
  logger: new Logger(),
  connectTimeout: 20000,
  dropSchema: false,
  entities: [
    Users,
    Notifications,
    etc...,
  ],
  migrations: [],
  subscribers: [], 
});

I also changed my typeorm script in package.json to
"typeorm": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli -f ./ormconfig.ts",

I also added synchronize: false at the entity level:
@Entity("notifications", {  synchronize: false, schema: "xxx", orderBy: {
  createdAt: "DESC",
} })

Please help,
Thanks
